# Switch 5VDC input on/off using an ESP32

Tags: arduino, switching, esp32

I’ve been wracking my brains with this for several days now. I bought a cheap watch winder and I want to modify it so that I can control the maximum number of turns per day using an ESP32 module and the upright-position sensor that the winder includes. My full code is up and running, working perfectly, and I’m able to calculate the tpds using the sensor, etc., but I’m stuck on a key point: how do I get the ESP32 to turn the rotation on and off?

The winder works with an on-off-on switch that controls two different rotation modes and in the middle is off, of course. The lead connected to the middle pin of the switch comes directly from the winder’s GND input. So it's providing GND when set to one mode or the other. The winder works with a 5VDC supply. “Downstream” from the switch, the circuit still remains powered to enable the winder to return to the upright position when the user “turns off” the device using this switch.

Anyway, what I was thinking as the best option was to control that GND input to the switch using the ESP32. That way, the device could be permanently set to one mode or the other with the physical switch, and I could control the on-off of said mode with the ESP32.

Because the device uses 5V, I can’t control this directly from the ESP32 (as far as I'm aware). I was thinking of a MOSFET switch control module, so I got an LR7843. But once I received it, I was surprised to see that the input voltage from the supply is dropped by nearly half on the output to the load… This wasn’t detailed anywhere in the module’s description; perhaps it’s common knowledge, but I didn’t know it. But the material point is that when I input 5V from the supply I get 3-3.5V output to the physical switch, which is essentially the same as I would get directly from the ESP32's pin...

So again I’m stuck. What would you recommend? Perhaps I’m making it more complicated than it should be?

This is my ersatz schematic of the basic components and connections involved in my switching attempt (the black dashed line shows where the switch's lead was originally connected to the winder):
[image: Ersatz schematic]

This is the LR7843 MOSFET Control Module I used:
[image: LR7843 MOSFET Control Module]

**UPDATE:** I've since been able to "solve" a part of this. Apparently the drop in voltage had to do with getting the 5V from the 5V pin on the ESP32 for the positive input of the LR7843 module while connected to my computer (as I was tweaking the script and testing the switch capacity). If I connect the ESP32 to a power supply that's able to provide higher amperage, then it's OK. So I must assume it has to do with a USB port not being able to provide enough amps for the module to work as expected. I've now connected the LR7843's positive input directly to the 5V supply powering the winder and ESP32, and I get the full 5V coming through to the Load. **HOWEVER, I'm also now measuring -0.7V when the signal coming into the switch is on low and, therefore, the switch is, in theory, disconnected.** ‍♂️ I'm wondering if this might cause issues and should I address it. My instinct is that I should, as, at the very least, it seems sloppy; but I'm also inclined to think it might have unwanted consequences. In my limited knowledge, adding a diode comes to mind (??). Or will it be fine and I should just leave it?

Comment: Please show a schematic of what you tried.

Comment: What exactly did you get? An LR7843 MOSFET or a module built using it with some extra components?

Comment: @JonathanS. Sorry about that. My understanding of schematics is rudimentary at best, which is why I didn't think it would be useful to include one  I've now added my best shot a one to my original post.

Comment: @Finbarr I used a built module, now pictured in my original post. (And I added its schematic in my sort-of-schematic of the overall attempt.)

Comment: "the input voltage is dropped by nearly half on output" - please explain what this means. Most people would understand "input voltage" to mean the level on the PWM pin, "supply voltage" to be the level on the + pin and "output voltage" to be the level on the LOAD pin.

Comment: Did you measure the voltage of the two inputs when disconnected? There is a good chance, that the MCU on the winder circuit also runs from 3.3 V. U3 seams to be a 3.3 V linear regulator.

Comment: @Finbarr I thought I had clarified sufficiently when I then say "the material point is that when I input 5V from the supply I get 3-3.5V output to the physical switch", but I've now edited my post to make it clear in that first statement. My power supply is 5VDC and, when the switch is on, I've current it running out to the Load, I measure 3-3.5VDC.

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure if this answers your question, please correct me if I'm wrong: when I measure across the switch's middle pin I get 5.25V and when I measure across one of the other two pins with the switch disconnected I get 1.9V.

Comment: I should perhaps add that I haven't gone ahead and tested switching the actual winder with this setup as I don't want to damage anything. I have however measured the load output from the module, and have tested using an LED, which lights up perfectly when switched (which, of course, means it isn't getting anywhere near 5V as it would blow out quite quickly if it were).

Comment: @Jens it seems you're right. I've searched the code and indeed U3 seems to be a voltage regulator, the 33 in the code meaning it regulates to 3.3V. Furthemore, measuring the open contact that's next to C6 I get 3.3V. However, the central pin on the "key" measures at 5.25V as I mentioned. So I'm guessing U1 brings the voltage back up (?)

Comment: "The lead connected to the middle pin of the switch comes directly from the winder’s GND input" and "the central pin on the "key" measures at 5.25V" cannot both be true if they're the same pin.

Comment: @Finbarr You are correct, the GND shouldn't measure a voltage.  Clearly my amateur status in electronics isn't allowing me to choose the correct terms to explain myself. ‍♂️ I was referring to the circuit loop measured on the positive end and the GND taken from the middle pin.

Comment: I have since been able to "solve" a part of this. Apparently the drop in voltage had to do with getting the 5V from the 5V pin on the ESP32 (at least while connected to my computer as I was tweaking the script and testing the switch capacity). If I connect it directly to the supply, I can get the full 5V to come through. HOWEVER, I'm now measuring -0.7V when the switch is on low/disconnected. ‍♂️ I'm wondering if this might cause issues and should I address it (adding a diode comes to mind??), or if it's fine and I should just leave it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense as there are no negative supply voltages anywhere in your circuit. What two points exactly are you measuring -0.7V between?

Comment: @Finbarr With the circuit connected as per my schematic, I have my negative probe on the LR7843's load output and my positive probe on one or the other of the on-off-on switch's side pins, say the yellow one. When the LR7843 module is switched to ON, I measure 3.3V across (@Jens was right, the input voltage is regulated down to 3.3V at that part of the circuit, not sure why I was seeing 5+V yesterday) and when the module is switched OFF I'm getting a reading of a bit over -2V, which drops down to -1.X, and finally settles down on -0.7V.

Comment: @Finbarr I should also add that even if I don't connect the LR7843 to the actual circuit, that is if I just connect it to the ESP32 and measure across the LR7843's load output and the ESP32's 3.3V output, when the LR7843 module is ON I measure 3.3V and when it's OFF I measure -0.7V. (In this instance, it doesn't go from -2 to -0.7V, it just goes directly to -0.7V.) In both cases, ie either connected to the circuit or not, the LR7843's + input is connected to the same 5V supply that drives both the ESP32 and the winder circuit, and of course its GND input is connected to common GND.

Comment: Returning a bit to my original question, perhaps there's another (maybe easier) way of switching the winder using the ESP32 that you guys could recommend? At this point, I'm thinking that the LR7843 is either not suitable for my needs or I've received a faulty module (or have damaged it in some way without realising it).

Comment: Personally I'd just use a small relay with a BJT controlled by the MCU

Comment: @Finbarr Any specific relay/BJT you could recommend for this purpose? I had been looking into using a BJT (or MOSFET) or a relay instead of the module, but got stuck. I don't think my knowledge is sufficient to fully understand how make this work, which is why I finally decided to go with an already-made solution... but it turns out my knowledge isn't even enough to get that working! 